# Como criar uma function de ajuda

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Como posso implementar uma funcionalidade em `jQuery / Javascript` que apareça uma tipo de ponto de interrogação assim que o usuário der 2 cliques em um `TextBox` e, quando ele clicar nesse ponto de interrogação, um **Help** de como ele possa preencher corretamenta o campo apareça?

Comment: Você já conseguiu estruturar seu HTML? Pode [edit] a pergunta inserindo esse código? Já conseguiu tratar o evento de duplo clique no campo? O problema está somente em mostrar o ícone de ajuda e a respectiva mensagem?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss  Já está estrurado o HTML, pois irei implementar isso em aplicação da empresa ao qual trabalho.

O problema é só o duplo clique e mostrar o icone de ajuda e a respectiva mensagem.

Comment: Você usa Bootstrap? Poderia usar os tooltips para mostrar o texto de ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#input').on('dblclick', function(){
  $('#help').show()
})
```

```css
#help{
  display: none;
}


a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
a.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  width:140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
a.tooltips span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid #000000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.8;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -76px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  De dois cliques em caso de duvida
  
  <a id="help" class="tooltips">
<img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-help-128.png" width="30">
<span>MENSAGEM;)</span>
  </a>
</label>
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Você pode fazer assim com `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, quando vc clicar 2 vezes na caixa de texto ele deve mostrar um texto de ajuda...
Para fazer isso, sete um id para seu textbox e faça com que o campo com a interrogação venha escondido e através do jquery faça uma função que seja chamado no double click desse id. Exemplo :

```
$( "#seu_id" ).dblclick(function() {
  $("#id_da_interrogacao").show();
});
$("#id_da_interrogacao").click(function(){
  //faça aqui seu código para mostrar o texto
})
```